# Why am I getting followinf message "NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element:"?

Tags: python, selenium

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div/div[2]/main/div[2]/div/section/div[2]/div/form/input")
```

gives the following message>

```
NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"/html/body/div/div[2]/main/div[2]/div/section/div[2]/div/form/
```

The website (URL) is:

https://sede.administracionespublicas.gob.es/pagina/index/directorio/icpplus

Comment: Please share your url or relevant html?

Comment: I shared the url. Many thanks @KunduK

Comment: Where is this `element` you want to locate ?

Comment: Acceder al Procedimiento button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `WebDriverWait()` and wait for element to be clickable and following xpath to click on the element.

absolute `xpath` is always fragile, you should use relative `xpath` to identify the element.
You can learn form here [Xpath cheatsheet](https://devhints.io/xpath)

```
WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@value='Acceder al Procedimiento']"))).click()
```

Import below libarries

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```

Comment: Works like a charm. But to understand how did you get  this "//input[@value='Acceder al Procedimiento']" ? Many thanks that is amazing. So each click line should include WebDriverWait because it takes time.

Comment: @user19562955 : I have given a reference link. you can check the link.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the element you wanted to click is not clickable you can use the same `locator` with below code or use the code as is.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by
import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui
import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support
import expected_conditions as EC

element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
   EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "submit")))  # if you want to click on the button Acceder al Procedimiento

element.click();
```